# JsonDeserializer is not working with gson

Tags: java, gson

I have a list(list contains the requiredFields and this list can get the dynamic data from text file) and I have api response jsonData.

Now, I need to extract the data from api(jsonData) response, only the required fields(what list contained fields). All this need to be done using gson serializer

```
 public class EDSJsonSerializer implements JsonDeserializer {

    final list<String>;  //  list can be populated by reading data from text 
 file

  //ex: list<Strin> is : [ab,bc]

     @Override
    public JsonElement deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        jsonElement => {"ab":"234234","bc":"wrwerewe","ww":"345fsd","456":"dfgdfg"}

        final Map map = new HahMap();

        map should contain only 2 elements {"ab":"234234","bc":"wrwerewe"}
        map can be populated with list above given as keys and values from json passed

    }
}


final String json = "";  // json is the api response string
 final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Map.class, new EDSJsonSerializer());

        final Gson gson = builder.create();

        final String map =  gson.toJson(json);

    it is not working as expected and not throwing any error/exception.
```

Please help me on this

Thanks,
Syamala.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `456` is not a valid Java class field name. It might be one reason of your problems even you might never use it from Json.

Secondly you migh better use `ExclusionStrategy` to decide which fields to de- & serialize.

In your case something like:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExcludeUnlistedFields implements ExclusionStrategy {
    @NonNull
    private Set<String> fieldsToInclude;
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        // if you need to restrict to specific a class/classes
        // add the checks here also
        return ! fieldsToInclude.contains(f.getName());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
 Set<String> fieldsToInclude = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("ab", "bc"));
 ExclusionStrategy es = new ExcludeUnlistedFields(fieldsToInclude);        
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
                              .addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(es).create();
```